# Add Or Condition to Entity in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Can you add an "Or" condition to an entity in the entity framework?  For example something like:

> Property1 == (1 or 2 or 3)

The message I get when putting the value of "1 || 2 || 3" or "1,2,3" or "1 or 2 or 3" returns this message:

> ```
> condition is not compatible with the type of the member
> ```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to do:

```
var results = entityCollection.Where(entity => entity.Property1 == 1 || entity.Property1 == 2 || entity.Property1 == 3);
```

Comment: I was afraid of that.  What I'd like to do is for the same condition to take place every time a query against that table is executed so that I don't have to write the above code each time I hit the table.

Comment: @Blakewell: Put the query in a utility class so you can reuse it.

Comment: @Reed Copsey: Are you missing an `entity =>`?

Comment: @Mark: Not anymore ;)  That happens when I goof and reword things too fast.. Thanks.

Comment: What if I want to concatenate "or's" on a loop the gets certain property?

Answer (score 18):

You should also check out predicate builder:
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

It's a bit more advanced, but if you have to dynamically chain conditions it's your best bet.

```
foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tried this, but you could try using `contains`.  Not sure about performance, but the code is smaller:

```
int[] vals = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var results = entityCollection.Where(entity => vals.Contains(entity.Property1));
```

Comment: `Contains` is only supported in EF 4, which hasn't been released yet (it's coming out the 12th with .Net 4).  There's is a release candidate on MS's website.

Comment: Didn't even think about that - I've been using EF 4 for a while so this seemed normal.